# Country has no timezone in PHP DateTimeZone

Tags: php, timezone

Is this a php bug? The country **Nederlandse Antillen** ('AN') does not register any timezone in `DateTimeZone`.

```
$country_code = 'AN'; // Nederlandse Antillen
print_r(DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::PER_COUNTRY, $country_code));
```

There may be other countries but I just happened to come across this one by accident.

Comment: I can only suspect they removed it because the country was dissolved in 2010. Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netherlands_Antilles

Comment: Interesting. So in short, it's not a country anymore then.